# Facing issue with org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound

Tags: spring-mvc

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/allconfig.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

my hello-servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.controller"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/Jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

allconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- <bean id="user" class="com.test.User"/>     --> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>   
</beans>
```

TestController

```
package com.test.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.test.model.User;

@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/home",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getHomePage(User user){

        return new ModelAndView("home", "user", user);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/processrequest",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processRequest(User user){
        System.out.println("request processed successfully");
    }
}
```

home.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "/TestController/processrequest" method="post">
    first name : <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
    last name : <input type="text" name="lastName"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me in resolving this issue:

Dec 21, 2015 12:39:38 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringTest/home.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'hello'

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the URL for which no mapping exists.

So either change the mapping to `@RequestMapping(value="/home*",method=RequestMethod.GET)`

or try hitting `/SpringTest/home` only.

Comment: I am using this url (http://localhost:8080/SpringTest/home) only to test the code. and tried to add * after home also.  no option works. and also changed the url mapping to / and not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `allConfig.xml` and also remove the config below in `web.xml`

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/allconfig.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

The framework will automatically lookup for `hello-servlet.xml` and you do not require an additional config file `allConfig.xml`

Change your `hello dispatcher servlet` mapping from `/*` to `/`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Make sure that you have `home.jsp` in the path  `WEB-INF/JSP/home.jsp` and
then when you hit the URL `localhost:8080/SpringTest/home` , `home.jsp` will be returned.

Now in `home.jsp` change your form action to `action = "./processrequest"`

```
<form action = "./processrequest" method="post">
    first name : <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
    last name : <input type="text" name="lastName"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

When you submit the form, your controller method will be called and the statement `System.out.println("request processed successfully");` will be executed and you can see the same in the console. But still your page show 404 error because you did not return anything from the controller. So make sure your controller method returns a jsp page so that the 404 error will be resolved as well.